# Reinsert or retokenize in Elasticsearch without dropping everything

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticserach 6.8 and I've the following situation:
We deployed the elastic service and after a few months we observed that we used the wrong tokenizer, or didn't normalize it, if you will.

We are storing the raw data in the document and also some tokenized values. One way to go would be simply applying the ascii folding filter to achieve something like:

```
Aplicação -> aplicacao
Açaí -> acai
Minha availiação -> [minha, avaliacao]
```

But today we obtain something like

```
Aplicação -> aplicação
Açaí -> açaí
Minha availiação -> [minha, avaliação]
```

Is there a way to fix this without having to reinsert everything as I have the raw values?

Edit: We are using UTF-8 and by normalize I mean the behavior of ASCII folding filter.

Comment: Q: So by "normalize", you mean `Açaí` should be searchable as `acai`?  Q: Out of curiosity, what character set is the "original" text?   ISO-8859-1?  Or "something else"?

Comment: We are using UTF-8. By normalize I mean the behavior of applying a ASCII folding filter.

Comment: By "not having to reinsert everything", do you mean that the reindex api is not what you are looking for? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-reindex.html

Comment: That is probably it. I will test it so I can properly answer you. Feel free to leave it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `reindex` API:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-reindex.html

This API call will allow you to reindex your documents if you have the `_source` available. The destination index should have the proper tokenizers before you reindex, so that the documents will have ascii folding applied.